# Add glow to animation in compositor when using sheepit renderfarm

Tags: animation, compositing-nodes

I'd like to use the compositor to add a fog glow to my animation but once I have it all setup and try to submit my file to Sheepit-renderfarm. I lose the fog glow effect I added using the compositor. Please help.

This is my render on my OWN PC
[image]

The Link to the Blend File (Sorry if its messed up)

[blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqmzy6jshgyrsir/WIP.zip?dl=0)

Comment: There is very little we can say, because you don't attach a Blend file and don't tell us which render farm you're using.

Maybe it's a better idea to render to multilayer EXR files first, and then do the compositing afterwards? That'll give you much more flexibility in the compositing stage.

Comment: I will edit this later sorry. Hang on

Comment: It's done I have edited the question I hope this provides you substantial info :(

Comment: There is still no blend file. Try stripping it down to the minimum that still shows your problem.

Comment: Seems to me that is a question that should be asked directly to the render farm support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer. One must never forget to plug the entire node setup into the Composite Node in the end to apply it to the render.

I simply forgot to plug it and left it at the Viewer Node whenever I save and close.

Comment: Oh my heavens, I just had that same problem yesterday.